# .Net Maui custom entry field not passing value from view model

Tags: .net, maui

I have a custom control Entry field , when I use this control in signup view and pass a value , this value will be null even I have enter a value

custom control Entry field is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BlogTemplate.ControlTemplates.ChicEntry">

    <ContentView.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ChicEntryControlTemplate">

            <Border 
                    StrokeThickness="0"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10">

                <Entry Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                       Placeholder="{Binding  Placeholder, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                       Margin="8,0,8,0"
                       BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource CardColorLight},
                            Dark={StaticResource CardColorDark}}"/>
                
            </Border>
    
        </ControlTemplate>
        
    </ContentView.Resources>
    
</ContentView>
```

with c# backend

```
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace BlogTemplate.ControlTemplates;

public partial class ChicEntry : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ChicEntry), string.Empty, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            var conttol = (ChicEntry)bindable;
            conttol.Text = newValue as string;
        });

    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(ChicEntry), string.Empty);

    /// <summary>
    /// The string to be edited.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
    public string Placeholder
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
        set => SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
    }
    public ChicEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Signup ViewModels

```
 public SignUpViewModel()
        {
            Title = AppResources.SignUp;
            SignUpCommand = new Command(SignUp);  
            // SignUpCommand = new Command(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../.."));
            LoginCommand = new Command(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(".."));
            //TermsCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync("https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/"));
        }

        private void SignUp(object obj)
        {
            var user = FulltName;
        }
```

the signup view

```
 <template:ChicEntry Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ChicEntryControlTemplate}"/>
```

and when I click on signup button the FullName will be null while I already have a value in entry field

Comment: `Text` is not a VM property, it is a property of the control itself.

Comment: thank you , but how can access the Text in the below action
                <template:ChicEntry Text="{Binding FulltName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   
                                    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ChicEntryControlTemplate}"/>

Comment: Hi, may I ask why the xaml is about ChicEntry and the backend is about ChicButton . Could you please post more relevant code? and what's the FulltName in viewmodel, which binds to it?

Comment: BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"